# Do you lose subscriptions to (and files of) mods if it went from free to paid?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam-workshop

Now that [Skyrim mods are partially not free](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/aboutpaidcontent), what happens to mods that have chosen to transition from the previously (and only) price of 'free' to '[insert any value that's not 'Free']', what happens to those mods that I'm subscribed to?

So far, I've noticed that *all* the addons I've subscribed to disappeared (as in: Subscription gone).
*And deducing that all the mods I've gotten in the years went from free to paid... The list went from like 50 to 3... All of them lockpick mods.*

Do I lose subscription and in turn, Steam deletes them all?
Do I get to keep them but in order to get updates (or a redownload) I have to "buy" to subscribe to it^?
Or do I automatically stay subscribed?

^ I'm only referring to mods that have transistioned from 'free' (the previous and only option) to 'paid'.

### Update

Great news everyone. [Everything's now free again](http://www.bethblog.com/2015/04/27/why-were-trying-paid-skyrim-mods-on-steam/)!
Check the [workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=72850) if you don't believe (or see [this announcement](https://steamcommunity.com/games/SteamWorkshop/announcements/detail/208632365253244218) for more information)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not relevant anymore. (See http://www.bethblog.com/2015/04/27/why-were-trying-paid-skyrim-mods-on-steam/ and http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=72850)

Comment: [Valve has put this on hold.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/3435tu/paid_mods_in_steam_workshop/) (This question should've been strictly about Steam in the first place anyway...) That means that the question and answer may still be relevant in the future. With that in mind, I've voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed in the first place. If the question topic is currently obsolete or not relevant, then that should be indicated in an answer. See [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797) and [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7235/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja I am the one who marked it for closing... Also, let's just wait and see...

Comment: I'll update my answer with an edit since it's the accepted answer already.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Steam deletes them all". If you previously had a mod that was free and is now paid, you will become Unsubscribed to that mod. Unsubscribing to a mod essentially deletes the mod and all of the files pertaining to it.

You have to buy all mods that aren't free (obviously), so in order to keep the files and your subscriptions you have to go find all of the ones that you were subscribed to and purchase them.

You will not automatically stay subscribed to mods that you have not purchased. There is no such thing as "Subscribed, but not installed."

The above answer is true for the Steam Workshop. I highly recommend [Nexus Mod Manager](http://www.nexusmods.com) for anyone wanting to get away from this catastrophe.

***UPDATE:*** Valve has listened to the feedback of the people and no longer allows paid mods on the Steam Workshop. You can no longer lose your subscriptions because a mod has converted to paid from free. I still recommend the Nexus Mod Manager over the Steam Workshop.

Comment: Good answer.  I'd give a 2nd upvote just for the Nexus Mod Manager suggestion.  I switched over when the Unofficial Skyrim Patch (a necessity in my mind) got too big for Steam to handle.

Comment: @tjd Thanks! I absolutely love the team over there at Nexus. All the mods, the manager, the multitude of games, the automatic updates...all of it. They are doing a wonderful job.

Comment: @aytimothy It's actually really easy. If you have any questions just let me know and I'll help you out. They have a really great forum over there and I've met a lot of nice people through their site. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is currently moot (as of 2015-04-27). According to Valve:

> #### Removing Payment Feature From Skyrim Workshop
>
> We're going to remove the payment feature from the Skyrim workshop. For anyone who spent money on a mod, we'll be refunding you the complete amount. We talked to the team at Bethesda and they agree.

<sup>Sources:

[Removing Payment Feature From Skyrim Workshop | Steam Workshop group announcement](https://steamcommunity.com/games/SteamWorkshop/announcements/detail/208632365253244218)

[Paid Mods in Steam Workshop | Reddit /r/Games](https://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/3435tu/paid_mods_in_steam_workshop/)</sup>

Comment: The actual refund goes into your Steam Wallet rather than back into the account the money originally came from, which has annoyed a fair number of people by the sounds of it.