# Which is the name of this HUD mod for ARK?

Tags: mods, ark-survival-evolved

I would like to know the name of this HUD mod:

[image]

I tried to find HUD mods on the [ARK's steam workshop site](http://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/workshop/), I only found **[ReHUD](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=536970545)**, and it isn't.

---

Original screenshot:

[image]

I don't know if it matters, but this person seems to be playing **[Pirate World](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=547377246)**, a total conversion mod for ARK. (I'm not really sure whether he is playing that total conversion mod.)

Comment: From the [steam tag wiki page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/steam/info): "This tag should only be used in regards to the Steam software itself, or a particular game feature, unique to Steam. If the game is being played through Steam, simply mentioning it on the body is adequate, and the tag should not be used." Examples of correct usage: [1](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/how-do-i-continue-downloading-a-game-in-steam-while-playing) [2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96370/how-can-i-move-an-installed-game-from-one-steam-library-folder-to-another)

Comment: From the [steam-workshop tag wiki page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/steam-workshop/info): "This tag is for questions regarding subscribing to user-generated content, or the process of publishing new items, levels, game modifications, or other content to the workshop specifically." Examples of correct usage: [1](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215540/do-you-lose-subscriptions-to-and-files-of-mods-if-it-went-from-free-to-paid) [2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242121/how-to-upload-a-mod-to-steam-workshop)

Comment: In other words, the fact that this game can be bought on Steam doesn't warrant the steam tag, and the fact it's a mod doesn't warrant the steam workshop tag (you're not even sure if you can find it there).  Also, reminder to everyone: please avoid getting into edit wars. If there's a disagreement over the content of a post please flag for moderation attention instead of adding and readding tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be the [Stat Bars](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=737297870&searchtext=) mod on Steam.

The following image is from their community page.

[image]